# Is it possible to find out last update date on a RavenDB document without loading it?

Tags: ravendb

I'm trying to get smarter about caching and have certain users whose entities are getting into 10s of megabytes. These entities are loaded every minute and most of the time they do not change (ie; they change a few times per day)

In order to avoid network roundtrips, I'd love to cache these entities on Azure worker role instances.

Is there a way to get at the timestamp of an entity without loading the whole entity and making it travel over the wire?

Alternatively, is there a way to /realiably/ and without additional license cost to synchronize RavenDB locally onto an Azure worker role instance and keep it updated with changes from the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Head function in the DatabaseCommands:

```
var metadata = _documentStore.DatabaseCommands.Head("customers/1");
var lastModified = metadata.LastModified;
```

More information: http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/commands/documents/how-to/get-document-metadata-only

Hope this helps!